# How to combine mulltiple IN clause in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, relational-division

I have two tables:
goods with column id and title
filter with column id
And one cross-join table: filter_good with columns filterid and goodid 
I need to find goods that match any filter in one list of filters ids and also match any filter in another list of filters ids.
I'm trying to achieve it using this query without luck:

```
SELECT
    goods.*
FROM
    goods
JOIN filter_good ON goods.id = filter_good.goodid
WHERE filter_good.filterid IN (3)
AND filter_good.filterid IN (1, 2)
```

How this can be done?

I need to return records that match only if there is a record with id 3 AND with id 1 or 2

Comment: Maybe I am missing something: `filter_good.filterid IN (1,2,3)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No, then filter will match on any of 1, 2, 3 but I need to match only if there is a record with id 3 AND with id 1 or 2

Comment: [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: In logic, when using sets, OR is the additive (union) operator for sets, often in common language expressed as 'and' and the 'AND' is set intersection operator often in common language expressed as 'at the same time'. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your question is really not that clear but you problably need an `EXISTS` clause:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    goods
WHERE 
  EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM filter_good 
    WHERE goods.id = filter_good.goodid
      AND filter_good.filterid IN (3)
  )
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM filter_good 
    WHERE goods.id = filter_good.goodid
      AND filter_good.filterid IN (1,2)
  )
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct answer but it is too complicated. What if there are 5 group of filters? May be there is another way?

Comment: @user2975535: yes there is another way. Several. None of them are really simple (the *problem* is not simple ...) See the relational-division tag for more hints.

Answer (score 0):

```
select g.id
from
    goods g
    inner join
    filter_good fg on g.id = fg.goodid
group by g.id
having bool_or(fg.filter_id = 3) and bool_or(fg.filter_id in (1,2))
```

Table aliases make it clearer.

Check the [`bool_or` aggregate function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html)

If other `goods` columns are needed wrap it in an outer query:

```
select *
from goods
where id in (
    select g.id
    from
        goods g
        inner join
        filter_good fg on g.id = fg.goodid
    group by g.id
    having bool_or(fg.filter_id = 3) and bool_or(fg.filter_id in (1,2))
)
```